# Single electron pumps, superconducting energy gap

Tags: electrons, superconductivity

I am seeking to find out how many electrons per gate cycle are pumped at different temperatures. The Single Electron Pump is made out of Al, with a $T_c=1.2\,\mathrm{K}$. This single electron pump is two-gate electron pumpthat is based on a single-electron transistor (SET).

Diagram of discussed SET: 
[image]

I know that:

$\Delta=e^2/2c\implies I=ef$

$\Delta>e^2/2c\implies I=2ef$

$\Delta<e^2/2c\implies I=ef$

However, how do I calculate the superconducting energy gap $\Delta$ with only the transition temperature of Al, $T_c=1.2\,\mathrm{K}$?

Comment: Please, be more specific about the pumping cycle, the charge stability diagram of your pump etc.

Comment: So, I have only heard of one kind of 2-gate resistor. However, as it's useful, I've added a URL of a diagram of this device. Cheers.